# $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ has the root lattice of type $A_1$.

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$ constructed from a root lattice $R$. It is well-known that if $R=A_1$, then $L \cong \mathfrak{sl}_2$ and this is widely used example in many books on Lie algebras. However, I have never seen a strict proof of this fact. How can we actually show the isomorphism?

Comment: This is surely discussed in just about any text discussing semisimple Lie algebras. I don't have them handy, but I imagine both Fulton & Harris and Humphreys treat this in some detail.

Comment: Both directions of this are also fairly straightforward exercises that I would recommend anyone studying Lie algebras to do.